# $f(x)=a\sin x + b \cos x\equiv 0$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Let $$f(x)=a\sin x + b \cos x$$
where a,b are some constants.

Let there are exists $x_1, x_2$ such that $$f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$$ $x_1-x_2\not =\pi k, k \in \mathbb Z $ .

Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. And is it $a=b=0$ in this case or not?

###My work

I see that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$.
$$a\sin x_1 + b \cos x_1=0 \Rightarrow \tan x_1=-\frac ba $$
$$a\sin x_2 + b \cos x_2=0 \Rightarrow \tan x_2=-\frac ba $$
Hence, $\tan x_1-\tan x_2=0$. Then $\sin(x_1- x_2)=0 \Rightarrow x_1-x_2=\pi k$.

But $x_1-x_2\not =\pi k$.

Where my mistake? How I need continue to solve my problem?

Comment: You assumed that a is nonzero, so this is a contradiction argument

Comment: @ArcticChar: Thank you very much!

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your argument.  If $a\ne 0$ we get this result.  But that contradicts the hypothesis.  So $a$ must equal $0$>  and if $a = 0$ then $b\cos x_1 = 0$ and $b\cos x_2 =0$.  If $b \ne 0$ then $\cos x_1 = \cos x_2 = 0$ so $x_1, x_2$ are multiples of $\pi$.  Thats a contradiction so $b = 0$.

Comment: If $tanx_1=tanx_2$, then $x_1-x_2=k\pi$, even if $a=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep $\tan$ out of the game.

When $(a,b)\ne(0,0)$ then the point $(a,b)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ has distance $A:\sqrt{a^2+b^2}>0$ from the origin, and there is a unique $\phi\in[0,2\pi[\>$ such that
$$a=A\cos\phi,\quad b=A\sin\phi\ .$$
It follows that
$$f(x)=A(\cos\phi\sin x+\sin\phi\cos x)=A\sin(x+\phi)\ ,$$
so that $f$ has two zeros differing $\pi$ modulo $2\pi$. Since such pairs of zeros have been excluded it follows that in fact $(a,b)=(0,0)$, so that $f(x)\equiv0$.

Comment: Why do we exclude the "two zeros differing π modulo 2π?"

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption that $a$ is $0$ is wrong. For $a\ne 0$ the result is true. But then we arrive at a contradiction, implying that $a=0\implies b=0$

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the solution is much easier than this.  We have the system $$a \sin x_1 + b \cos x_1 = 0, \\ a \sin x_2 + b \cos x_2 = 0,$$ so $$a \sin x_1 \sin x_2 + b \cos x_1 \sin x_2 = 0, \\ a \sin x_1 \sin x_2 + b \cos x_2 \sin x_1 = 0,$$ hence $$b (\cos x_1 \sin x_2 - \cos x_2 \sin x_1) = b \sin (x_2 - x_1) = 0,$$ and similarly, $$a \sin x_1 \cos x_2 + b \cos x_1 \cos x_2 = 0, \\ a \sin x_2 \cos x_1 + b \cos x_1 \cos x_2 = 0,$$ hence $$a (\sin x_1 \cos x_2 - \sin x_2 \cos x_1) = a \sin (x_1 - x_2) = 0.$$  But since $x_1 - x_2 \ne \pi k$ for any integer $k$, $\sin (x_1 - x_2) \ne 0$ and we are forced to conclude that $a = b = 0$.

Note that this approach does not create any issues with division by $0$--we might be multiplying by $0$, but this only creates the possibility of extraneous solutions.  But since there are no solutions except $a = b = 0$, we don't need to perform any additional checking.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=a\sin x+b\cos x$$
where $a,b$ are two real constants ($\,a,b\in\mathbb{R}\,$) .

If there exist $x_1, x_2$ such that $$f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$$ and $\;x_1-x_2\not=\pi k\;,\;$ for any $\;k\in\mathbb{Z}\;,\;$ then

$a=b=0\;$ and $\;f(x)=0\;$ for all $\;x\in\mathbb{R}\;.$

***Proof :***

$\begin{cases}
f(x_1)=0\\
f(x_2)=0
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
a\sin x_1+b\cos x_1=0\\
a\sin x_2+b\cos x_2=0
\end{cases}$

The determinant of the previous system is

$D=\left|\begin{matrix}\sin x_1\quad\cos x_1\\\sin x_2\quad\cos x_2\end{matrix}\right|=\\\quad=\sin x_1\cos x_2-\cos x_1\sin x_2=\sin\big(x_1-x_2\big)\;.$

Since $\;x_1-x_2\not=\pi k\;,\;$ for any $\;k\in\mathbb{Z}\;,\;$ it results that

$D=\sin\big(x_1-x_2\big)\ne0\;.$

By using Cramer’s Rule, we get the solution of the system :

$\begin{cases}
a=\dfrac{\left|\begin{matrix}0\quad\cos x_1\\0\quad\cos x_2\end{matrix}\right|}D=0\\
b=\dfrac{\left|\begin{matrix}\sin x_1\quad0\\\sin x_2\quad0\end{matrix}\right|}D=0
\end{cases}$

Hence,

$a=b=0\;$ and $\;f(x)=0\;$ for all $\;x\in\mathbb{R}\;.$

Comment: Since you know that the determinant is nonzero, you need nothing else to conclude, because a homogeneous system always has the zero solution and, in this case, it is unique.

Comment: Of course you are absolutely right, but I felt it would be better for the original poster to write all the steps.